# Blazor WASM - How to enable request over http

Tags: c#, api, http, graphql, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on a Blazor WASM app to connect a GraphQL API but is over HTTP (I have no control/ownership over the API) this is the error when I send the request:

[image: Error]

Just in case you ask, I already tried to send the request over HTTPS and always recive *TypeError: Failed to fetch* even if I tried with https in GraphQL playground

There is a way to enable http request to access the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution for this problem:

[Cors-Anywhere](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere)

this application allows me to create a server to parse http to https.

Thanks